# ArcGIS Pro - Rename attachments in attachment table based on relationship field

Tags: python, field-calculator, arcgis-pro, attachments, arcade

I'm looking for a Python 3/Aracade script to field calculate `ATT_NAME` in an attachment table based off of the `REL_GLOBALID`.

So where `REL_GLOBALID` is `{67CECF26-9BE8-4E37-9408-3BC156DA51C0}`, I'd like to rename `ATT_NAME` to `Photo 1` and then where there is another attachment with the same `REL_GLOBALID`, I'd like that to be changed to `Photo 2`. See attached photo

[image: example photo]

Answer (score 1):

This task is very easily (and quickly) accomplished in ArcGIS Pro with an update cursor. See my practical example below. You can see the names updates between table 1 and table 2. You will need to adjust the *fields* variable at the top of the script, as well as adjust the *'test_table'* name in the update cursor on line three. The *'test_table'* can be replaced with a string of the name of your table in the current map document, or a string pointing to the path of the file on disk.

```py
fields = ['GUID', 'ATT_NAME']
featureClass = 'test_table'
update_dictionary = {}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureClass, fields) as updates:
    for row in updates:
        if row[0] not in update_dictionary.keys():
            update_dictionary[row[0]] = 1
        else:
            update_dictionary[row[0]] += 1
        row[1] = 'Photo ' + str(update_dictionary[row[0]])
        updates.updateRow(row)
```

**BEFORE CODE**
[image]

**AFTER CODE**
[image]

**GIF OF PROCESS**
[image]

Comment: Oh I use ShareX! Dude, it is friggen AWESOME. 

https://getsharex.com/